# My contact form will not validate its input fields. It will submit an email to me while my input fields are blank. Any suggestions?

Tags: php, forms, validation, contact-form

As stated, my php contact form will send me a blank email message however, it will not validate null input values. Any suggestions? I've tried about everything I know to do.

I'm also wondering if there is a way that I can redirect to a thankyou.html page on submit. I remember the php being something like "header..." to redirect.

```
 if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'email@example.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) = 0; {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

 // If there are no errors, send the email
 if (!$errName && !$errEmail) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
} else {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
   }
 }
  ?>
```

HTML...

```
 <!--FORM-->
 <form role="form" action="contact.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal align-center">
 <div class="form-group col-centered">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4 text-align-center">NAME</label>
    <div class="control col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
          <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?> 
    </div>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group col-centered">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4 text-align-center">EMAIL</label>
    <div class="control col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="name" class="form-control">
          <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?> 
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label  col-sm-4 text-align-center">PHONE</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btnSize btn btn-default btn-lg"><strong>SAVE $150</strong></button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `if (!$_POST['name']) = 0; {` that for one thing, is failing for 2 reasons. Plus, mail's "From", expects an email address.

Comment: I did that earlier and for whatever reason deleted it! I'll try again.

Comment: Your code contains too many errors. Have a look at this https://www.formget.com/php-contact-form/ that looks like pretty good code. Or https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters--net-2595

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm new to php and contact forms, that's disappointing that it has errors. I'll read through those tutorials. Thanks.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  There is actually an error in that first link, the email regular expression only matches, `w@w.w` or `w-(+)@w-(+).w-(+)` they for got the `[\w-]+` slash in their character classes. `/([w-]+@[w-]+.[w-]+)/` either that or its being rendered wrong on the page,  Just saying. :-D

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix it's a start. I could have come up with a dozen others, but it was late and my head was in a "go to bed Fred" state ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I been coding my new polymorphic exception class so I was in the bug seeing mode. ;-/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = !empty( $_POST['name'] ) ? $_POST['name'] : false;
    $email = !empty( $_POST['email'] ) ? filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) : false;

    if( $name && $email ){

        $from = 'Demo Contact Form';
        $to = 'email@example.com';
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email";

        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
        }
    }else{
        $errors = [];
        if( !$name ) $errors [] ='Invalid Name entered';

        if( !$email ) $errors [] ='Invalid Email entered';

        $result= '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.implode('<br>', $errors ).'</div>';
    }
}
```

`filter_var()` returns the filtered var or false on failure, so with that and the ternary `{if} ? true : false;` we can normalize your input and simply everything after that.

We check the inputs as soon as possible, that way we run as little code as needed to get to the end result.  We know right away if they are good and can skip the majority of the email code, and output our error message.

Logically we can dump the error flag, an in the else we know one or both inputs are false.  The array and implode is just a simpler way of putting in a line break.  It's also easier to extend by just adding another input in with minimal code changes.  As you can see it would be very easy to add another ternary statement, an and condition and an error message.  ( only 2.5 ish lines )

One thing I would do on top of that is this

```
 $post = array_map('trim', $_POST);
```

And then change all the `$_POST` to `$post`, this will account for names added in as spaces or extra white space from Copy and Pasting, a common occurrence.

Further you may be able to minimize the errors like this

```
}else{
    $result= '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.implode('<br>', array_filter([
        $name ? false : 'Invalid Name entered',
        $email ? false : 'Invalid Email entered',
    ])).'</div>;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, i'll check these out. I followed a different tutorial about sanitizing and validating everything mentioned from another comment here. There's so much to learn! I don't think I could ever develop without references to everything.

Comment: I been doing it almost 7 years, it just takes time and practice.

Comment: I started in 2009! lol but to be fair I went for graphic design and there was a few courses on web design. I just happen to get into development but never really went past html/css. Now i'm in IT and i've learned java, js, sql, and a bunch of other junk. But surprisingly I still have to consistently research. new to php though!